# How to create a NewsML in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-parsing

We are currently working on news website there we have an requirement to extract NewsML xml files. 
Is there any tool in asp.net/C# to extract newsML xml files ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is a lot easier with the newer XML API Linq-2-XML (XLinq).

var root = XElement.Parse(xmlText);  // or directly .Load(fileName)

List tifNames = root.Descendants("TIFNAME").Select(e => e.Value);

Comment: Thank you for your input @akram Khan i will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this ,you can generate a .xsd ,then build class by xsd.exe /c xsdname.xsd,then serialize xmlstring to this class.